# Time series loadflow powerfactory via python

Tags: python

Can anyone help me with running time-series load flow in powerfactory using python? by sharing the script.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The script is built into the software - right click the `object of interest`, select `Execute Script`, choose `Time-Series` from the list and execute it to full fill your requirement

Comment: Thanks I know it is built into the software, but I wanted to build it in python.However, I manged to to solve it.